# Remove tag if tag attribute class contain only that class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove tag by its class attribute but the attribute should only contains that class only and not any other class.
My code

```js
$("#click").on("click", function() {
  $(".text").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="default text">One</div>
<div class="text">Two</div>
<button id="click">
  Press
</button>
```

So when I press the button it should show the first div tag and remove other containing only that class.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$("#click").on("click",function(){
  $('[class="text"]').remove();
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$("#click").on("click",function(){
  $('[class="text"]').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="default text">One</div>
<div class="text">Two</div>
<button id="click">
  Press
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
$('[class="text"]').remove();
```